# Saving UI design in XML format

Tags: xml, eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-gmf

We are developing an IDE (based on Eclipse GMF) to design user interfaces. Those Designs will be then saved in XML format.

Is there any opensource tool available to do the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

Although still incubation, I think XWT could fill your needs. See [Eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/XWT) http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/a/ab/XWT.pdf

Answer (score 2):

GMF uses EMF and EMF can save in XML format. By default it saves in XMI, but you can coerce it into XML.